# Cobra Kai is a deep cut

Tags: grammar

Does "Cobra Kai is a deep cut" mean "Cobra Kai is very impressive" (a deep cut into your memory)?

Elon Musk tweeted on Nov 18:
**Cobra Kai is a deep cut**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite rare slang.  If you look at replies to the tweet you see a lot of

> I don't understand what deep cut means

> googling deep cut now

Wiktionary has a definition: a [deep cut](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deep_cut) is an obscure song by a well-known musician, or by extension, an obscure work, but one that has a small, but loyal fan base, or is only appreciated by true fans.

Musk is saying "not many people know about this, but I think it's great".